# Printing out variables and values in a Groovy object

Tags: reflection, groovy

How can I print out the (public and internal) variables and their values of a Groovy object?

I.e

```
class X
{
  def X = 10
  def Y = 5

  private void doPrivate()
  {
      def Z = 3
  }
}
```

Should give

```
X, 10
Y, 5
Z, 3
```

This has to be a dynamic solution, i.e at runtime.

Comment: Are you talking about reflection?

Answer (score 125):

`dump()`

For example

```
println "ddd".dump()
```

Prints:

> java.lang.String@2ef900 value=dddd offset=0 count=4 hash=3078400

Comment: dump() does not print, it returns a string.  You will need to print the results.  i.e. println "ddd".dump()

Comment: Jenkins threw this on my face :)

`org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods dump java.lang.Object`

Comment: Jenkins just wants you to whitelist the method in the scriptApproval screen.

Answer (score 45):

You mean like this?

```
def a = "Hi"

a.properties.each { println "$it.key -> $it.value" }
```

Gives:

```
class -> class java.lang.String
bytes -> [72, 105]
empty -> false
```

[edit]

With your edited question, this would give you:

```
class -> class X
y -> 5
metaClass -> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass@16de4e1[groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@16de4e1[class X]]
x -> 10
```

I don't think it's possible to get the Z value at runtime...  The only way I can think of to do it is via the AST...

Answer (score 0):

Having a function you can call on an object itself is convenient but doesn't exist out of the box.  If you don't mind polluting the namespace on `Object`'s metaClass, you can monkey patch it with something like this:

```
Object.metaClass.printit { -> println org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.toString(delegate) }
'asdf'.printit() // prints 'asdf'
```

`printit` isn't the greatest name, but `print`, `println` and `dump` are all taken.