# How can I list the variables already available inside Jenkinsfile?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use some variables like repository name, branch names, build number,... from inside the `Jenkinsfile` but I am not able to find any documentation regarding this.

Is there a way to print them so I can see what's available? How?

I think it may be related to [Printing out variables and values in a Groovy object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069687/printing-out-variables-and-values-in-a-groovy-object)

Update

```
this.binding.variables.each {k,v -> println "$k = $v"}
```

I tried to include the code above but now execution fails with

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use field groovy.lang.Binding variables
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectField(StaticWhitelist.java:177)
```

Answer (score 13):

To see environment variables, try:

```
node {
  sh 'env | sort'
}
```

Comment: This does not show variables defined inside "script" blocks.

Comment: Like @AntonioPetricca I'd love to know how you do this for non-env (Groovy?) variables defined in blocks.  Especially if you're using the declarative syntax.

Answer (score 12):

From your `Pipeline` job configuration page, click 'Pipeline Syntax' link on the left nav. It opens and on its left nav click `Global variables`. It lists many variables which could be used within `Pipeline` script, including a set of environment variables are made available to all Jenkins projects.

An example of loading variable values from Groovy:

```
mail to: 'devops@acme.com',
    subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) is waiting for input",
    body: "Please go to ${env.BUILD_URL} and verify the build"
```

Comment: Yes that is the official documentation.

Comment: where is this "Global variables section" I can't find it.

Comment: They are now under "Pipeline Sintax", at the end of the page.
Or you can just append /pipeline-syntax/globals to your job URL

Answer (score 4):

in our case we used the following to get all groovy-defined variables within a jenkinsfile groovy pipeline:

```
groovyVars = [:] << getBinding().getVariables()
groovyVars.each  {k,v -> print "$k = $v"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to execute you pipeline inside a sandbox, and the operation you do considered insecure as you trying to get low level access.

If you not admin of this Jenkins you have no option but to ask your admin a permissions - that 's the sandbox for.

If you sandboxed yourself on an occasion - simply remove the checkbox under pipeline window.

if you still wanna be sandboxed and you have admin rights
got to http://your_jenkins/scriptApproval/ 
find your function access request and approve it.

In case of success of all three options above 
you ll proceed to the next error in your script

groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: binding for class: WorkflowScript

GL

UPD: remove leading "this" to get through

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find [Global variables](https://qa.nuxeo.org/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals) that are available in Pipeline directly, you'll find amoung them the environment variables in [env](https://qa.nuxeo.org/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#env)

Comment: pls provide more detailed solution.