# how to further debug to expose the values in the element in groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, hashtable

Hi i am new to groovy and i have an issue that i am facing. Currently i am trying to see the values inside `typeCache[alias]` which seems to be a hashtable.

```
   protected static       Hashtable typeCache = new Hashtable();

   logger.error "this is type cache : " + typeCache[alias].get(indx)[1];
```

when i output the element i get the following result in the logs :-

```
 this is type cache : [com.abcd.util.TypeElement@5dc97ce, com.abcd.util.TypeElement@270a8a6, com.abcd.util.TypeElement@5d421487]
```

am i able to expose further on the elements to see what is in them and what is it doing ?? i am used to php programming and usually in situations such as this i would do a var_dump is there an equivalent of var_dump in groovy ??

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object has a  method, which generates a

> `public String dump()`
>
> Generates a detailed dump string of an object showing its class, hashCode and fields. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#dump%28%29

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069687/printing-out-variables-and-values-in-a-groovy-object) contains an example, but make sure to read the comment, as the answer is not corrected as of yet.