# Jenkins: env in pipeline from Jenkinsfile is null

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Please help. `env` is null.

Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
  println "Your ENV:"
  println env.dump
  println "Your params:"
  println params.dump
}
```

Jenkins output:

```
[Pipeline] properties
[Pipeline] node
Running on foobarquux in c:\workspace\123abc
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Your ENV:
[Pipeline] echo
null
[Pipeline] echo
Your params:
[Pipeline] echo
null
```

I expect that my environment variables will not be null. I expect `env.dump` not to be null and to see something beyond `Your ENV:` when `println env.dump` executes.

---

After reading very helpful comments from @mkobit, I realized I needed parentheses for `dump`, and even with them Jenkins throws a security exception.

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is unclear what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: @mkobit. I edited the question to show what I expect.

Comment: Where are you setting the `dump` environment variable or the `dump` build parameter? What makes you think they should not be `null`?

Comment: @mkobit See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069687/printing-out-variables-and-values-in-a-groovy-object answer by Dónal. I can see all the environment variables that should be set in jenkins_url/systemInfo. In addition I set some of my own.

Comment: `dump()` is a method in that example, and the dynamic nature of Groovy and how the Jenkins global variable resolution works is that it is looked up as a property and if not present is `null` (see the source code [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/c69e3862bf26ac122dbc26345f1bb73b906c6824/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsScript.java#L112-L138)). I would be surprised if `dump()` does not throw a security exception in the Jenkins security sandbox.

Comment: I added the `()`. And you were correct that it threw a security exception.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close my own question. There's a lot more I need to be asking here. I am trying to integrate Jenkins, Gitlab, and Danger (http://danger.systems/) This is really a larger question that I should rewrite in a separate question.

Answer (score 7):

`${WORKSPACE}` only works if it is used in an agent (node)! Otherwise it comes out as `null`.

I have `agent none` at the top of my pipeline because I have a few `input` steps that i don't want use heavyweight executors for. And I was setting an environment variable in the top-level `environment {}` block that used `${WORKSPACE}`. For the life of me I couldn't figure out why it was being set to null. Some other thread mentioned the workspace on an agent, so i moved that definition into a step on an agent, and lo and behold, when you set a var with WORKSPACE while running on an agent, it all works as expected.

The sidebar here is that if you are using a top-level `agent none`, the `environment` and presumably other pre-stages blocks are not running in an agent. So anything that relies on an agent will behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy's optional parenthesis [requires at least one parameter](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses), which is different than Ruby.

> Method calls can omit the parentheses if there is at least one parameter and there is no ambiguity:

So, to call the [`dump()` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#dump-java.lang.Object-) you would do `env.dump()` or `params.dump()`. However, this method will not be whitelisted and you will get a security exception (if you are running in the sandbox or using any sort of Jenkins security) because this would print out all fields of the object.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to StephenKing for pointing out, i check again with a new fresh Jenkins instance. see comments inside

Assuming the job has 2 parameters [str1=val1, bool1=true] :

```
node {
  // Print the value of a job parameter named "str1"
  // output: val1
  println "${params.str1}"
  
  // Calling the dump() function to print all job parameters (keys/vals)
  // NOTE: calling this method should be approved by Jenkins admin
  // output: .... m=[str1:val1, bool1:true] ...
  println params.dump()

  // Same as the above. 
  // output: .... m=[str1:val1, bool1:true] ...
  println "${params.dump()}"
  
  // SYNTAX ERROR, the '$' is not expected here by the parser 
  //println ${params.dump()};

  // This appears in the question, but it seems like this is not
  // what the author meant. It tries to find a param named "dump"
  // which is not available
  // output: null
  println params.dump

}
```

Comment: Why should this work? String interpolation without being a string? Or am I missing some groovy language feature here?

Comment: Gave an error... `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [acceptGitLabMR, addGitLabMRComment, archive, bat, build ...`. @StephenKing are you saying this was not a valid suggestion from @chenchuk? It looks odd to me.You could do `"${env.dump}"` but that seems redundant. I'm used to Ruby string interpolation which would look like `"#{env.dump}"`. In ruby I would just use `env.dump`.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK this answer is incorrect, esp. if you confirm it with the error message. String interpolation in Groovy just works like in Ruby, only replacing the `#` with a `$` sign.

Comment: Thanks StephenKing, i recheck and modify the answer. the code shows the "params" but the same is true for "env"